# utplsql checking column value comparision

Tags: oracle, utplsql

I am new to UTPLSQL and i installed 3.04 version
i checking column value ut.expect( o_ename ).to_equal('Ford');
o_ename will contain Ford.

but when i executed test case test is failing saying that
 testename
      Actual: 'FORD' (varchar2) was expected to equal: 'Ford' (varchar2) 
      at "UT3.TESTPROC", line 11 ut.expect( o_ename ).to_equal('Ford');

Finished in .01 seconds
1 tests, 1 failed, 0 errored, 0 disabled, 0 warning(s)

here are procedure and packages.
 CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE p2(i_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE,o_ename OUT emp.ename%type)
   AS
    BEGIN
      p1(7902, o_ename);
     dbms_output.put_line('Inside P2 : Procedure P1 output is '||o_ename);
   END;

create or replace package testproc as
    -- %suite(find name)

```
--%test(testename)
 procedure testename;
 end;
```

create or replace package body testproc
  as
   procedure testename as

```
   i_empno emp.empno%TYPE := 7902;
  o_ename emp.ename%type;
    BEGIN
  p1(i_empno, o_ename);
    dbms_output.put_line(o_ename);
   ut.expect('Ford').to_equal('Ford');
   ut.expect( o_ename ).to_equal('Ford');
    END;
```

set serveroutput on
begin
ut.run('testproc');
end;

Failures:

1) testename
      Actual: 'FORD' (varchar2) was expected to equal: 'Ford' (varchar2) 
      at "UT3.TESTPROC", line 11 ut.expect( o_ename ).to_equal('Ford');

Finished in .01 seconds
1 tests, 1 failed, 0 errored, 0 disabled, 0 warning(s)

help me how to compare table column name  with actual name

Answer (score 1):

With SQL data **case matters**. The error message is quite clear: the actual value of the data is `'FORD'` but your expected value is `'Ford'`. The test correctly fails because these are two different strings.

The solution is quite simple - pass the correct expected value:

```
ut.expect( o_ename ).to_equal('FORD');
```